# Simples equação de divisão em java

Tags: java

Boa tarde, sou iniciante em java e preciso fazer o seguinte calculo na linguagem

Por exemplo:
(8/7)*100 = 114%

(4/7)*100 = 57,14%

(90/112)*100 = 80,35%

Porém da forma que estou desenvolvendo ele não me retorna o resultado correto

```
  double total = (90/112) * 100 ;
  System.out.println(total);
```

e ele me retorna 0.0 no console

como faria pra ele me retornar o resultado real?

Answer (score 10):

( *90 / 112* ) é uma divisão de inteiros.

O java faz o cast pra double que arrendonda pra baixo (**0**) devido ao resultado: 0,8035... quando é feito a multiplicação: 0 x 100 = 0.

Você pode realizar o cast de pelo menos um dos operadores para obter o resultado desejado:

```
double total = ((double) 90 / 112) * 100;
System.out.println(total); // 80.35714285714286
```

Outras formas de realizar o cast:

```
double total = (90d / 112) * 100;
double total = (90.0 / 112) * 100;
```

Answer (score 4):

Existem duas maneiras de resolver isso:

```
double total = (90/112d) * 100 ;
System.out.println(total);
```

Ou:

```
double total = (90./112.) * 100 ;
System.out.println(total);
```