# Como NÃO arredondar valores?

Tags: java, matemática, tipagem, float, divisão

Preciso de um valor exato mas meu código sempre arredonda para baixo:

```
float percentageUsed =  6050492416 / 8258998272;   
System.out.println(String.format("Porcentagem: %.2f", percentageUsed));
```

No caso tinha que me retornar 0.73, mas ele sempre me devolve 0.0.

Como pegar o resultado exato?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Divisão resultando sempre em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252461/divis%c3%a3o-resultando-sempre-em-zero)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Simples equação de divisão em java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134766/simples-equa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-divis%c3%a3o-em-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo menos um dos números da divisão deve ser do tipo `float` e está usando inteiro, então a divisão é feita como inteiro e depois o resultado inteiro era guardado em um variável do tipo `float`. Use o sufixo `f` no literal para dizer que o número é `float`. De forma mais simples:

```
System.out.printf("Porcentagem: %.2f", 6050492416f / 8258998272f);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/FloatDivision.java).

Na verdade um número tão grande nem aceita como um `int`, o código nem compila. Se quisesse um resultado inteiro teria que usar o sufixo de `long`, o `L` ou `l` para dar certo.